# Calling checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError in Swift 2.0

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

I am having some issues migrating from Swift 1.2 to 2.0 particularly understanding error handling when calling methods from objective-c API. For example, I can't  implement the method `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError` correctly. According to the Swift documentation for this method it will return a Bool.  I want to check if a folder (`self.baseURL`) exists and tried the two following approaches:

```
let folderExists: Bool
do{
       try folderExists = self.baseURL!.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(){

        } catch let error as NSError {

        }
}
```

And:

```
let folderExists: Bool
var error: NSError?
do{
       try folderExists = self.baseURL!.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error){

        } catch error as NSError {

        }
}
```

But neither approaches work. I also thought that the Swift implementation of error throwing functions with the word `AndReturnError` would be shortened to `checkResourceIsReachable` but that does not seem to be the case.
I am sure I am doing something fundamentally wrong here and if someone has a suggestion for where to look I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method indeed returns a bool, it hasn't been modified to follow the new `do try catch` mechanism of Swift 2: it doesn't `throw`.

So you just use it like this, without `do try catch`:

```
var error:NSError?
let folderExists = self.baseURL!.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error)
```

Comment: I just checked as well, the definition is still without throw
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public func checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool

Comment: I think in Swift 3 this is now `checkResourceIsReachable()` and just returns `Bool` for `URL` type.